# Merging images in Java FX

Tags: java, image, javafx, javafx-2

I want to merge two JPGs (from the class `javafx.scene.image.Image`) using JavaFX 2.0. 
I think one way should be to convert them somehow into `BufferedImage` (not sure how to do that), and then make it in the old Java way.

Is there any solution available for this in JavaFX?

Thanks!

Comment: What does merge mean?  Can you use an [ImageInput](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/effect/ImageInput.html) with a [Blend](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/api/javafx/scene/effect/Blend.html) effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It seems there is no built-in function for this in FX (it should be available soon). I found this post:
http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/26/save-node-to-image-in-javafx-2-0/
With this class, you can save your node to an image file. I could use the output image as the merged one.

If anyone have a better solution, pease share it.